# No property found for TickFrequency in <Slider> in XAML on Xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, slider

I am working in Xamarin Studio, trying to learn C# and XAML and I am having some trouble with a bit of XAML for a simple program. I am trying to use a  and change the TickFrequency, but it doesn't seem to recognize it or any Tick related attributes. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="HelloWorld.GreetPage">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
            iOS="0, 20, 0, 0">
        </OnPlatform>
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <StackLayout
        BindingContext = "{x:Reference slider}">
        <Label
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Text="{Binding Value,
                StringFormat='Font Size: {0:F0}'}"/>
        <Slider
            x:Name="slider"
            Maximum = "64"
            Minimum = "16"
            TickFrequency="1"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

The error I receive says "No property, bindable property, or event found for "TickFrequency"

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a `TickFrequency` in Window.Forms/UWP/..., but there is no analog to that in Xaramin.Forms : https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Slider/

Comment: I see, I've found the correct documentation for that now, I was looking in the wrong place. Is there a way to get that same effect with  Slider in xamarin?

Answer (score 0):

For adding ticks in xamarin forms in android and iOS apps, you can try [this](https://xamarinexperience.blogspot.com/2019/03/how-to-add-tick-marks-on-sliders-in.html)